# Divs position in metro style

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the tiles div's position in metro u. This is for SharePoint so I cant use use any javascript only css/html. Problem is with missig div on left. Please help

[Sample in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygogouao/)

```
<style type='text/css'>
  body { margin:0; padding:0; }
.clear { clear:both; }
#wrapper { margin:0 auto; width:1400px; }
#header { width:990px; height:120px; background: #0E83CD ; margin:5px auto;}
#block1 { width:646px; height:389px; float:left; background: #64BB5D; margin:5px; }
#block2 { width:110px; height:150px; float:left; background: #EB6890 ; margin:5px; }
#block3 { width:323px; height:190px; float:left; margin:5px; }
#block4 { width:646px; height:190px; float:left; margin:5px; }
.color1 { background: #E7333F ; }
.color2 { background: #0AA444 ; }
.color3 { background: #F40D43 ; }
#footer { width:990px; height:120px; background: #3C6DF0 ; margin:5px auto;}
#header:hover,#block1:hover,#block2:hover,#block3:hover, #block4:hover { background:#888888; -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg) translateX(1px) translateY(1px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
}
</style>

<div id="wrapper"> 

      <div id="block4" class="color1"> </div><!--block-long-->
    <div id="block3" class="color3"></div><!--block-short-->
    <div id="block3" class="color3"></div><!--block-short-->

    <div class="clear"></div> 

             <div id="block3" class="color3"></div><!--block-short-->



    <div id="block1"></div><!--block-big-->


      <div id="block3" class="color3"></div><!--block-short-->
          <div id="block3" class="color3"></div><!--block-short-->

  <div class="clear"></div> 

        <div id="block4" class="color1"> </div><!--block-long-->

          <div id="block4" class="color2"> </div><!--block-long-->



    <div class="clear"></div>


</div><!--wrapper-->
```

Comment: hard to tell what block is 'missing'. put something that identifies each block on you jsFiddle, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/st2vudqa/ then say which block is 'missing' and what you expect it to be instead.

Comment: Yes sorry, missing is square below 4 where the white space is. It should be same square like 4 but it all collapse when I copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

look this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqsyv35b/), one block was missing, and better use class instead id, it you need apply it for several elements. I just add class below for missing block, and replace margins you used for #block3 to new class .block-3. Just remember, every id must be unique, so you better to move all styles from ids to classes

```
.block-x {
    margin: 204px 5px 5px -328px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome ! and how to make it responsive with no external libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer... I have made some correction in your code like "using class at the place of id" and i also inserted a missing div. Hope it is that you exactly want.

Your CSS

```
<style type='text/css'>
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
.clear { clear:both; }
#wrapper { margin:0 auto; width:1400px; }
#header { width:990px; height:120px; background: #0E83CD ; margin:5px auto;}
#block1 { width:646px; height:389px; float:left; background: #64BB5D; margin:5px; }
#block2 { width:110px; height:150px; float:left; background: #EB6890;margin:5px; }
.block3 { width:323px; height:190px; float:left; margin:5px; }
.block4 { width:646px; height:190px; float:left; margin:5px; }
.color1 { background: #E7333F ; }
.color2 { background: #0AA444 ; }
.color3 { background: #F40D43 ; }
#subdivholder{width:336px; float:left;display:inline-block;} <!--New inserted code-->
#footer { width:990px; height:120px; background: #3C6DF0 ; margin:5px auto;}
#header:hover,#block1:hover,#block2:hover,.block3:hover, .block4:hover { background:#888888; -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0deg) translateX(1px) translateY(1px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
}
</style>
```

Your HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
<div class="block4 color1"> </div><!--block-long-->
<div class="block3 color3"></div><!--block-short-->
<div class="block3 color3"></div><!--block-short-->
<div class="clear"></div> 
<div id="subdivholder"><!--New inserted code-->
         <div class="block3 color3"></div><!--block-short-->
         <div class="block3 color3"></div><!--block-short-->
</div>
<div id="block1"></div><!--block-big-->
<div class="block3 color3"></div><!--block-short-->
<div class="block3 color3"></div><!--block-short-->
<div class="clear"></div> 
<div class="block4 color1"> </div><!--block-long-->
<div class="block4 color2"> </div><!--block-long-->
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!--wrapper-->
```